# Trying to find a way to list all friday dates between 2 dates in powershell

Tags: list, powershell, date

How to identify a list of dates with a specific day of the week between 2 dates in Powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem, it's fairly straightforward:

```
$date = [datetime]::parseexact('07-Feb-20', 'dd-MMM-yy', $null)
$date2 = [datetime]::parseexact('28-Feb-20', 'dd-MMM-yy', $null)    

$fridays = 1..($date2 - $date).Days | % {$date.AddDays($_)} | ? {$_.DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday'}
```

Just make sure you put your dates in correctly! There's likely a more succinct way to do it.

Comment: Nicely done; worth mentioning that the `$null` implies parsing by the _current_ culture's rules; with the specific date (string) format shown, you can also cast directly to `[datetime]` in a culture-_invariant_ fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Every PowerShell `[datetime]` object contains a `.DayOfWeek` parameter which will tell you the day of the week.  You can interate through the date items with another `[datetime]` feature, the `.AddDays()` method.  So something like this:

```
$StartDate = [datetime]'datehere'
$EndDate = [datetime]'datehere'
$ThisDate = $StartDate
$AllFridays = @()
While ($ThisDate -le $EndDate)
{
    If ($ThisDate.DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday') { $AllFridays += $ThisDate }
    $ThisDate.AddDays(1)
}
```

This was just a first crack.  Obviously, you could find the first friday, and then add days 7 at a time until you were past the End date, but I leave that optimization as an exercise for the reader.  :)