# How to identify a list of dates with a specific day value between 2 dates in powershell

Tags: list, powershell, date, compare

So I have this code (thanks to [@reeeky2001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/706970/reeeky2001)) that answer my other post [Trying to find a way to list all friday dates between 2 dates in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60120570/trying-to-find-a-way-to-list-all-friday-dates-between-2-dates-in-powershell) :

```
$FiscalStart = [datetime]'2019-03-31'
$date2 = Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$EvaluateDates = 1..($date2 - $FiscalStart).Days | % {$($FiscalStart).AddDays($_)} | ? {$_.DayOfWeek -eq 'monday'}
$EvaluateDates
```

So let's say we are on feb 09, 2020. if I run the following code, the last monday will be feb 03, 2020. How could I exclude the last date, So the next monday (feb 10, 2020) is in the future? How could I exclude any dates where the next monday would be in the future ? Assuming this code could be run anyday of the week...

Comment: Why exclude? Why not just `($date2 - $FiscalStart).Days` -> `(($date2 - $FiscalStart).Days + 1)`?

Comment: Bingo :) thanks man ! that work with ($date2 - $FiscalStart).Days - 7)

Comment: I just answered something very similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60120674/8507473  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I added "-and $_ -lt (get-date)"

```
$FiscalStart = [datetime]'2019-12-31'
$date2 = Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0
1..($date2 - $FiscalStart).Days | % {($FiscalStart).AddDays($_)} | 
  ? { $_.DayOfWeek -eq 'monday' -and $_ -lt (get-date)}


Monday, January 6, 2020 12:00:00 AM
Monday, January 13, 2020 12:00:00 AM
Monday, January 20, 2020 12:00:00 AM
Monday, January 27, 2020 12:00:00 AM
Monday, February 3, 2020 12:00:00 AM
```